# What happens to persisted RDD once Spark Job finishes?

Tags: apache-spark

What happens to a persisted  Spark RDD once the spark job gets finished with Success?

Do we need to explicitly write some Code to unpersist as well?

or

Does unpersisting happens automatically for each persisted RDD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do we need to explicitly write some Code to unpersist as well?

Yes

> Does unpersisting happens automatically for each persisted RDD?

No, You need to do it explicitly by calling
    `RDD.unpersist()`
or
    `df1.unpersist()`
and always unpersist the df after the end of the lineage, after the last action that involves the persisted/cached df.

Comment: Yes Sure.. Thank you very much for your clean answer. I will unpersist my DF after the last action .

Comment: @ sanket : Is it good practice to persist a RDD if I have only one Action in my Spark Job. Do I get any benefit in terms of performance if I persist a RDD

Answer (score 1):

The official documentation of spark says

> Spark automatically monitors cache usage on each node and drops out old data partitions in a least-recently-used (LRU) fashion. If you would like to manually remove an RDD instead of waiting for it to fall out of the cache, use the RDD.unpersist() method.

Please take a look at http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#removing-data